# TypeScript how to define type on only the first element in array when destructuring

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ethers.js

The first element (`ethersProvider`) needs a type annotation. But Typescript compiler can infer the second element.
The following code doesn't compile.

```
  const [ethersProvider, setEthersProvider]:[ethers.providers.Web3Provider|undefined, {}] = useState();
```

How to leave the second element to type inference without using 'any' type since it make type weaker.

Answer (score 2):

React's `useState` hook accepts a generic type parameter for the state value. You can provide your union type `ethers.providers.Web3Provider | undefined` in place of that parameter instead of using a manual type annotation for the return value:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwCYFMBmBDArgG3hgZzhRgAsUoCBfONKCEOAchPMqYG4AoUSWRLARQBlGBhgoadBsygoMAYxicuXNFgB2S4BA1wAwg0gaUG+AAoAlIi5w4C3QXgBtW3eJkKBAAr0AbsCoUAA0bgD0YQB6APxudkIwAKKelL4QAUGhdhExbgC6cAC8cIIiYhIAPKxeAHRg-oG1AOooAEYAzGkZFHAAPiUaqGjAJkgAfFbcVFxAA)

```ts
import {default as ethers} from 'ethers';
import {useState} from 'react';

function Component () {
  const [
    ethersProvider,
  //^? const ethersProvider: ethers.ethers.providers.Web3Provider | undefined
    setEthersProvider,
  //^? const setEthersProvider: Dispatch<SetStateAction<ethers.ethers.providers.Web3Provider | undefined>>
  ] = useState<ethers.providers.Web3Provider | undefined>();
}
```